# How to implement RLE in C

Tags: c, rle

I have recently tried coding RLE in C, I have rewritten the whole thing ~5 times and all of times it just says "" or just null. Here is my latest revision, can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char rle(char src[]) {
    char chr = src[0], res = "";
    int count = 0, len = strlen(src), tmp = 0;
    for (int i; i < len; i++) {
        while (chr == src[i]) {
            count++, i++;

        }
        chr = src[i];
        tmp = i;
    }
    res+=src[tmp] + snprintf(NULL,0,"%d",count);
    return res;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%s", rle("aaaaa"));
}
```

Tried comparing current character and next one, didn't work.

Comment: you need to learn how strings work in C, because creating an empty string and adding to it doesn't work

Comment: Start by enabling warnings.  This shouldn't even compile:  `char res = "";`  You're assigning a pointer to a `char`.  Do you understand how that makes no sense?  *Fix your warnings.* Don't bother posting here until it at least compiles cleanly.  If you don't know how to eliminate the warnings, then *that* should be the subject of the post.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to _never_ modify the loop iterator (`i`) from inside the loop body. Doing so only serves a single purpose and that is to wildly confuse everyone including yourself.

Comment: `res+=src[tmp] + snprintf(NULL,0,"%d",count)` won't do what you seem to expect it to do. Strings in C just doesn't work like that. Please take some time to read more in your beginners books.

Comment: Also, `rle` returns a `char`, but you're trying to pass the result to a `%s` format in `printf`.  You should have gotten a warning about that as well.  Do you understand why that makes no sense?  Try to learn the difference between a `char`, i.e. a single character, vs. a `char *`.  *Fix your warnings.*  It's pointless to try to run code that has pointer mismatch errors.  It can't work, so there's no point.

Comment: Before you start "coding RLE" you need to learn : 1. pointers and arrays 2. Strings. Start from something easier like calculating the string length ot similar

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

`char` is a *character type*, not a *string type*. `char` represents a single character - one byte of information.

A [*string*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) is really a pointer to the first character of a sequence of bytes, always terminated by a zero-byte. Most commonly typed as a *pointer-to-char* (`char *`) or *array-of-char* (`char []`).

Strings require *space* - memory; a *buffer*. You must allocate this memory in some way - an automatically allocated array, a block of dynamic memory (that must be [re]sized manually), a static pool, etc.

Strings in C cannot be combined with the `+` operator. You must use string functions like `strcat`, string-wise I/O functions such as `sprintf`, or manually manipulate the individual bytes in a string.

`snprintf` returns an `int`, not a string. This value represents the number of bytes written to the buffer, or the number of bytes that *would have been written*, in the event that truncation occurs, or `-1` on error.

Here is a basic implementation of [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) to study, but you may want to pick up your [C textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/2505965), and re-read the chapters on types and strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int rle(char *dest, size_t length, const char *src)
{
    size_t bytes = 0;

    while (*src) {
        size_t remaining = length - bytes;
        size_t sp = strspn(src, (char []) { *src, 0 });
        int rc = snprintf(dest + bytes, remaining, "%zu%c", sp, *src);

        if (-1 == rc || rc >= remaining)
            return -1;

        bytes += rc;
        src += sp;
    }

    dest[bytes] = 0;

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char source[] = "aaaaabbbbcccaab";
    char result[64] = { 0 };

    if (0 == rle(result, sizeof result, source))
        puts(result);
    else
        fputs("Result failed (I/O error or buffer too small)\n", stderr);
}
```

```
5a4b3c2a1b
```